# How to limit the length of function name shown by (which-function-mode t)

Tags: which-function-mode

I am using `(which-function-mode t)` to show current function name / org-heading on the mode line.  I would like to limit the number of characters it shows on the mode line, but I couldn't find any option like `max-func-name` in `which-func.el`.

I can limit the string by redefining `which-func-update-1` with `(which-function)` replaced by `(truncate-string-to-width (which-function) 30)`:

```
(defun which-func-update-1 (window)
  "Update the Which Function mode display for window WINDOW."
  (with-selected-window window
    (when which-func-mode
      (condition-case info
          (let ((current (truncate-string-to-width (which-function) 30)))
            (unless (equal current (gethash window which-func-table))
              (puthash window current which-func-table)
              (force-mode-line-update)))
        (error
         (setq which-func-mode nil)
         (error "Error in which-func-update: %S" info))))))
```

But it is too hacky..

I tried to use `advice` as follow:

```
(defadvice which-func-update-1 (around testing activate)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'which-function) (lambda () (truncate-string-to-width (which-function) 30)))) 
    ad-do-it))
```

But it generates infinite loop.

Anyone know how to limit the string length without modifying `which-func.el`?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inspecting `which-function`'s source, this was found at the end of the definition:

```lisp
    ;; Filter the name if requested.
    (when name
      (if which-func-cleanup-function
      (funcall which-func-cleanup-function name)
    name))
```

(I have no idea whether this was added in a recent Emacs version.)

Therefore, setting `which-func-cleanup-function` seems to be the "official" way to customize it's output now.

For example:

```lisp
(defun my-which-func-cleanup-function (str)
  (truncate-string-to-width str 30))
(setq which-func-cleanup-function #'my-which-func-cleanup-function)
```

Edit: Correct argument usage

Edit2: Correctly use `defun` outside of `setq`

Comment: Should the "s" be "str"?

Comment: The return value of `defun` is undefined.

Comment: @Basil oh I didn't know that, thank you for pointing it out, I just always assumed that `defun` returned the function symbol

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `around` advice use `filter-return` which will get the return value of the advised function and can do what it likes with it:

```
(advice-add 'which-function :filter-return
            (lambda (s) (truncate-string-to-width s 30)))
```

Comment: I suggest either a) using `define-advice`; b) using a named function in place of a `lambda`; or c) passing a `name` property in the last argument to `advice-add`, so that the advice can easily be removed as needed.